# JavaScript Switch/Case Best Practices for Complex Logic Trees

Tags: javascript, syntax

I've recently been in a code syntax formatting debate and would like to get the opinion of the broader JavaScript community. I personally prefer this switch/case structure for complicated condition trees but other developers seem to dislike it. Below I will post my preferred switch/case structure and the if/else equivalents.

Rather than debate preferences, why is this switch/case code acceptable or unacceptable and the specific reasons? If the other alternatives are better, why?

```js
// My preferred switch/case block

switch (true) {
  case testA()              : return 'A';
  case testB() || testG()   : return 'B';
  case testC()              : return 'C';
  case testA() && !testB()  : return 'ZETA';
  case a === b && c !== d   : return 'foo';
  default                   : return 'bar';
}

// if-else alternate #1

if (testA()) {
  return 'A';
}
if (testB() || testG()) {
  return 'B';
}
if (testC()) {
  return 'C';
}
if (testA() && !testB()) {
  return 'ZETA';
}
if (a === b && c !== d) {
  return 'foo';
}
return 'bar';

// if-else alternate #2

if (testA())               return 'A';
if (testB() || testG())    return 'B';
if (testC())               return 'C';
if (testA() && !testB())   return 'ZETA';
if (a === b && c !== d)    return 'foo';
return 'bar';
```

Comment: They all work. I almost always abhor uses of `switch` but this looks reasonable (probably one of the most reasonable uses of `switch` I've seen). Another alternative to the lower sections is to remove the `else`s, since they're superfluous after the `return`s. Another thing to consider is if saving the `test` calls in variables first might be good, rather than possibly re-testing the same thing multiple times.

Comment: You make good points. I'm going to update the if-else structures in the code example with your recommendations because I don't want that distracting from the main point of the question. The function calls are meant to represent a computed property or something that is the combination of multiple other conditions.

Comment: once you remove the _else_ from the alternative **#1** now you have is an alternative **#2**, just with extra artifacts and lines.

Answer (score 0):

> once you remove the *else* from the alternative **#1** now you have is
> an alternative **#2**, just with extra artifacts and lines.

---

It is all about style; what is easier to Read and easier to Refactor in the case of logic needs to be updated. It all depends on your use case and intention when writing the code.

Personally, I prefer a good and simple Switch-Case statement over lines of nested If-Else logic. All the time I see those If(){} Else If(){} I want to scream in pain and run away from that code.

In this case, Alternative #3 is clean, compact, easier to read and refactor. I can see quickly on this example logic will require to be refactored, and the Switch-Case statement can require more work than the simple If solution.

Comment: Alternative #2 looks nice, but I argue it's annoying to debug because you have to add back in the brackets and then remove them again.